# Different Ways of Date Comparision in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, date

In MySQL there are multiple ways, to compare dates (DATE and DATETIME fields). I'm asking me whether there are advantages or disadvantages (performance, query parser, human-readability, ...) on the different options).

Here are some variants, I know (I think there are more...):

```
SELECT my_date = 20140101
SELECT my_date = "2014-01-01"
SELECT DATE(my_datetime) = 20140101
SELECT YEAR(my_datetime) = 2014 AND MONTH(my_datetime) = 1 AND DAY(my_datetime) = 1
SELECT my_datetime BETWEEN "2014-01-01" AND "2014-01-01 23:59:59"
```

Are there more possibilities?

I think, that a comparision using the date-functions (DATE, YEAR, MONTH, DAY) is very ineffective as the query optimizer can not use a index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### From the pure technical point of view

Yes, all of the variants which make use of a function evaluation are likely to be slower than the other solutions. (Although some might be sped up by the optimizer, but with MySQL I would not count on that.)

I would not expect a performance difference between the first and the second variant. One could distinguish between `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` as type of the column.

- `TIMESTAMP` is stored in seconds since hour zero of all unix timestamps (1970...), so both your values would need to be transformed before the database can be searched for them.
- The `DATETIME` values are stored as an integer in a format like your first variant, so this might be slightly faster than the second variant, but since you are not constructing dynamic values there, the string will be transformed once at the beginning of the execution so the overhead is most likely negligible.

You can read about the internal structures in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html).

### The semantics

Actually your statements are not really comparable.

Assuming that the type of the column is `DATETIME`, those two queries

```
SELECT my_date = 20140101
SELECT my_date = "2014-01-01"
```

would find columns with `2014-01-01 00:00:00`, but not with `2014-01-01 23:59:59`.

The other three queries would find both rows.

From the last three queries, two make use of functions and are therefore not advisable. Since [using BETWEEN for datetime column types is not that good from a semantics point of view](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (especially since the introduction of fractional seconds in MySQL 5.6.4) I would most likely choose this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE
my_datetime >= "2014-01-01" AND my_datetime < "2014-01-02"
```